# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named {directory}

Tags: python, python-3.x

When I call `/Users/rgupta75/github/ece-prm/.venv/bin/python -s /Users/rgupta75/github/ece-prm/deploy/hcc_k8_deploy.py stage` I receive an error -

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ece_prm_agent' line 4, in

This is my code snippet

```
import sys, os, requests, subprocess, json
from pathlib import Path # requires python 3.4+
os.environ["env"] = "local"
from ece_prm_agent.utils.cyberark.cyberark import cyberark
```

and below is my folder structure image -

[image]

Surprisingly, when run from IDE it works fine but not from terminal.

Comment: Try to use the current directory path using  ```./```

Comment: What you've shown has `cyberark` directly under `ece_prm_agent` and not in a `utils` module like in your import statement.  Also does `ece_prm_agent` have an `__init__.py`?

Comment: @KyleParsons updated snippet

Answer (score 1):

That error means that the module `ece_prm_agent` wasn't found in `sys.path`. It was probably working on your IDE because it is being executed from the current directory `ece-prm` itself which as [documented](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path) is allowed:

> When a module named `spam` is imported, the interpreter first searches for a built-in module with that name. If not found, it then searches for a file named `spam.py` in a list of directories given by the variable `sys.path`. `sys.path` is initialized from these locations:
>
> - The directory containing the input script (or **the current directory** when no file is specified).
> - **`PYTHONPATH`** (a list of directory names, with the same syntax as the shell variable PATH).
> - The installation-dependent default.

Assuming this is your file tree

```
$ tree
.
├── deploy
│   └── hcc_k8_deploy.py  # Let's say this just calls cyberark.py::cyberark()
└── ece_prm_agent
    └── utils
        └── cyberark
            └── cyberark.py  # Let's say this just prints "Success"
```

Running it from the directory itself would run successfully

```
$ pwd
/home/nponcian/Documents/ece-prm
$ python3 deploy/hcc_k8_deploy.py 
Success!
```

While running it outside would fail

```
$ pwd
/home/nponcian
$ python3 /home/nponcian/Documents/ece-prm/deploy/hcc_k8_deploy.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/nponcian/Documents/ece-prm/deploy/hcc_k8_deploy.py", line 1, in <module>
    from ece_prm_agent.utils.cyberark.cyberark import cyberark
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ece_prm_agent'
```

As stated in the docs above, you should set `PYTHONPATH` so that Python can find the import modules relative to `ece-prm`

```
$ export PYTHONPATH=/home/nponcian/Documents/ece-prm/
$ python3 /home/nponcian/Documents/ece-prm/deploy/hcc_k8_deploy.py 
Success!
```

Or if you want to do it within the Python file `ece-prm/deploy/hcc_k8_deploy.py`

```
from pathlib import Path
import sys
sys.path.append(str(Path(__file__).parent.parent))
...
```

Comment: Yes that worked. IS there a way to export python path in python code itself?
I tried `sys.path.append(os.path.abspath(os.path.join('..', 'ece_prm_agent')))` but it didn't worked.

Comment: I updated my answer on how to do this within the Python code, see last part. Could you check if it works?

Comment: Probably the better thing to do instead of munging the path inside the script would be to install `ecrm_prm_agent` with `pip`.  This requires having a `setup.py` for `ecrm_prm_agent`.  The lighter weight solution would be putting your scripts in the same module structure as `ecrm_prm_agent`.

Comment: Well in that case, I believe exporting the `PYTHONPATH` which is a 1 line command would be preferred as it is the easiest to integrate (whether manual scripts or Dockerfile) as it's so easy to set/update.